# Break build if code is not documented in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

Is is possible to break build if code documentation is not provided or it is not provided properly.

Example here I have method without documentation. For this build needs to fail because method is not documented.:

```
  public onSuccessUpload(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Example here I have method incorrect documentation. For this build needs to fail because method doesn't have documented parameter:

```
  /**
 * Executes when each file is uploaded successfully. 
 */
  public onSuccessUpload(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Example here I have method incorrect documentation. For this build needs to fail because method doesn't have documented parameter properly. Document point to `string` and different name:

```
  /**
 * Executes when each file is uploaded successfully.
 * @param {string} text Success Message.
 */
  public onSuccessUpload(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Here is correct:

```
  /**
 * Executes when each file is uploaded successfully.
 * @param {any} data response from file upload.
 */
  public onSuccessUpload(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Is it possible to do this in TypeScript and Angular 4?

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript compiler doesn't actually care about JSDoc comments, except when it is trying to understand a JavaScript file - so you'll need the addition of TSLint.

TSLint can be configured to check lots of extra stuff that the compiler doesn't care about, there is a [ruleset for TSLint with JSDoc.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-jsdoc-rules)

Having said all this, the best TSLint rulesets are moderate rulesets.

Comment: Do you know how to use `tslint-jsdoc-rules`/ After installation I added `"jsdoc-require": [
            true
        ]` but it doesn't work.